# GLSL having strange black faces with the second mesh

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

platform: Windows10
context: OpenGL, glew, Win32

So I loaded 2 meshes(using a simple OBJ parser, which only reads the triangulated mesh), with vertexpos,uv and normal data. The first mesh is lighted okay. No black faces.The second one looks like this.
[The Strange Effects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EnBlH.jpg)

[image]

- my vertex shader:

```
    #version 440
    
    in vec3 pos;
    in vec2 tex;
    in vec3 nor;
    
    uniform float Scale;
    uniform mat4 perspective;
    uniform mat4 model;
    
    
    out vec3 normaldir;
    out vec2 texOut;
    out vec3 FragPos;
    
    void main()
    {
        normaldir = normalize(mat3(transpose(inverse(model))) * nor);
        gl_Position = perspective * model * vec4(pos.xyz, 1.0);
        texOut = tex;
        FragPos = vec3(model * vec4(pos, 1.0));
    }
```

- my fragment shader:

```
    #version 440
    uniform float Scale;
    uniform sampler2D diffuse;
    uniform sampler2D normal;
    uniform vec3 viewPos;
    //uniform sampler2D normalMap0;
    
    
    in vec3 normaldir;
    in vec2 texOut;
    in vec3 FragPos;
    
    layout(location = 0) out vec4 FragColor0;
    
    
    void main() 
    {
    
    
        vec3 lightPos = {2,6,0};
        lightPos.x = sin(Scale)*5;
        lightPos.z = cos(Scale)*5;
        vec3 lightDir = normalize(lightPos - FragPos); 
    
        vec3 lightColor = {1.0,1.0,1.0};
        float specularStrength = 1.6;
    
        float diff = max(dot(normaldir, lightDir), 0.0);
        vec3 diffuseD = diff * lightColor;
    
    
        vec3 viewDir = normalize(viewPos - FragPos);
        vec3 reflectDir = reflect(-lightDir, normaldir); 
    
        vec3 ambient = {0.0,0.2,0.4};
        
        float spec = pow(max(dot(viewDir, reflectDir), 0.0), 25);
        vec3 specular = specularStrength * spec * lightColor; 
    
        vec3 diffuseCol = texture(diffuse, texOut).xyz;
        vec3 result = (ambient + diffuseD+ specular) * diffuseCol;
    
        FragColor0 = vec4(result, 1.0);
    }
```

Comment: The issue is related to the mesh(-loader), not to the shader program. *"[...] which only reads the triangulated mesh [...]" - *Does the obj file contain quads?

Comment: First thing I would do is check the normals and look for degenerate triangles and/or NaN.

Comment: I made sure everything is triangulated. I made the meshes in maya. I double check the obj files and their normals, no issues found in there. Very strange

Comment: @user14285157 Anyway the shader code doesn't cause the issue. Do you use a Wavefront (OBJ) loader library or did you write the loader yourself? What is the type of the indices (byte, short, int)? Is there an overflow?

Comment: @Rabbid76 I used a simple obj loader which I found online. The indices are `unsigned int`. Other parts are reading okay, only the normals.

Comment: @user14285157 Possibly some of the normals are backface normals. Try to invert them:  `if (dot(viewDir, normaldir) < 0.0) { normaldir *= -1; }`

Comment: @Rabbid76 I just debugged my indices and they are fine. Only problem was reading the `vn`data, they turned out to be all 0.0000. very confusing

Comment: @user14285157 If the _vn_ data is 0, then the problem is not the shader code.

Comment: @Rabbid76 hi I tried debug again. the normals on RAM are correct. And I also tried your methods, they didn't work either. so I did this  `FragColor0 = vec4(normaldir*3, 1.0);` The some area are fine(colorful) however there are area remains black.

Comment: @user14285157 What happens if you do  `FragColor0 = vec4(abs(normaldir)*3, 1.0);`?

Comment: You have to invert `normaldir` before `float diff = max(dot(normaldir, lightDir), 0.0);`

Comment: @Rabbid76 Thanks guys I just solved it. very dumb bug. I bind the wrong size of buffer. very strangely it worked on some meshes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry I made a very dumb mistake. Thank you for all your support @Rabbid76  (Yes I did inverted the normals yes) @paddy

#### The problem was Binding the normal buffers. I bind `glm::vec2 * size` instead of `glm::vec3 * size` for normals' buffers